# Is this XML document well done?

Tags: xml

I checked validation and no errors came up , but I am not sure is it formed well overall . Am I missing the point in making XML file ? Don't mind polish languauge here , I am more concerned about overall structure of this docoment . I have to make an schema based on this , so I would be happy if someone would tell if its good enough.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<srodek xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="moje_hobby.xsd">
   <autor>
       <imie> Jakub </imie>
       <nazwisko> Kłopotek Główczewski </nazwisko>
    </autor>
   <podstrona nazwa_strony="moje_hobby.html">
   <nagłówek>
        <logo>
        <image href="img/dol.png"></image>
        </logo>
        <tytuł> Siatkówka </tytuł>
   </nagłówek>
   <menu>
        <lista>
                <punkt> Historia siatówki </punkt>
                <punkt>Zasady gry
                        <podpunkt>punkt,set,mecz</podpunkt>
                        <podpunkt>sklady</podpunkt>
                </punkt>
                <punkt>Ankieta</punkt>
                <punkt>Powrót do góry </punkt>
        </lista>
    </menu>
    
        
            <naglowek1 nazwa="Kto wymyślił siatkówkę"/>
            Dyscyplinę sportu, którą dzisiaj nazywamy siatkówką wymyślił w 1885 roku William Morgan nauczyciel ze szkoły w miejscowośc Holyocke w stanie Massachusetts. Miała to być halowa gra zespołowa na podobieństwo koszykówki, która byłaby jednak mniej męcząca i przeznaczona dla ludzi w średnim wieku,zajmujących się prowadzeniem interesów.Morgan stworzoną przez siebie dyscyplinę nazwał „mintonette”, jednak widzowie pierwszego turnieju siatkówki,rozegranego w 1896 roku wSpringfield, obserwując lot piłki nad siatką, nazwali ją „volleyball” – latająca piłka.
            <image href="img/william.jpg">William Morgan </image>
            <naglowek1 nazwa="Pierwsze zespoly i FIVB" />
            Siatkówka szybko zyskiwała nowych zwolenników w Ameryce i na innych kontynentach. W krótkim czasie w Europie i Azji zaczęły powstawać zespoły siatkarskie. Stopniowo wykształcały się reguły współczesnej siatkówki – od 1918 roku zespoły siatkarskie liczą sześciu graczy, zaś w roku 1920 wprowadzono regułę trzech odbić piłki przez jeden zespół.
            <image href="img/olg.jpg" >Pierwsze mecze </image>
            W 1947 roku powstała Międzynarodowa Federacja Piłki Siatkowej (FIVB). Jej pierwszym prezydentem został Francuz Paul Libaud. Tę funkcję pełnił do 1984 roku.Na Kongresie FIVB w Los Angeles kierowanie organizacją przekazał Meksykaninowi Rubenowi Acoście, który jest szefem do dzisiaj.
            <image href="img/FIVB.jpg">FIVB</image>
            <naglowek1 nazwa="Pierwsze mistrzostwa"/>
            W 1949 roku rozegrane zostały I mistrzostwa świata mężczyzn, a w 1952 I mistrzostwa świata kobiet. W turnieju męskim wygrał ZSRR przed Czechosłowacją i Bułgarią (Polska była piąta), a w kobiecym ZSRR przed Czechosłowacją i Polską.
            W igrzyskach olimpijskich siatkówka zadebiutowała w 1964 roku w Tokio. Wśród kobiet zwyciężyła Japonia przed ZSRR i Polską. W turnieju męskim pierwszy był ZSRR, druga Czechosłowacja, a trzecia Japonia. Rok później w Warszawie rozegrano pierwsze zawody o Puchar Świata mężczyzn. Od 1973 roku takie rozgrywki mają kobiety.
            <image href="img/mistrzostwa.jpg" >Mistrzostwa 1952 </image>
        
    
     <stopka>
     Copyright Jakub Kłopotek Główczewski 2020
     </stopka>

    </podstrona>
    <podstrona nazwa_strony="punkt,set,mecz">
    
    <naglowek1 nazwa="Podstawy siatkówki"/>
    
    Z założeń siatkówka nie jest trudnym sportem do opanowania . Jednak by zostać dobrym graczem trzeba naprawdę wykazać się dobrą dyspozycją sportową , oraz chęcią. W tym akapicie umówimy jednak podstawowoe zasady siatkówki. 
Mecz (mężczyzn) trwa do trzech wygranych setów , każdy z setów to 24 punkty , a punkty zdobywa się jeden po drugim. Na boisku może przebywać maksymalnie 6 graczy , możliwe są także zmiany, w które nie bedę się zagłebiał ponieważ jest to torche bardziej skomplikowane. Po zdobyciu punktu (który zdobywa sie trafiając w pole przeciwnika , bądz zmuszenie go do wybicia piłka poza pole) przechodzi się na zagrywkę gdzie zadownik według ustawienia posyła zza linii końcowej piłke w pole przeciwnika . Zagranie w aut jest równoważne ze zdobyciem punkta przez przeciwnika. Maksylamna ilość odbić to 3 (bez bloku) , 3 odbicie zazwyczaj kończy się atakiem , 2 zazwyczaj idzie przez rozgrywającego a 1 to strice przyjęcie piłki. W dużym skrócie to wszytskie zasady gry w piłke siatkowką .
    
    <image href="img/boisko.png" > </image>
    
    
    
    
    
    

    </podstrona>
    <podstrona nazwa_strony="sklady.html">
        
            <naglowek1 nazwa="Składy w siatkówce"/>
                <naglowek2 nazwa=">W siatkówce profesjonalnej każda pozycja jest inna (oprocz 2 przyjmujących) i pełni inną rolę."/>
                
        <image href="img/pozycje.jpg"/>
        <tabelka>
            <row>
                <col>Pozycja</col>
                <col>Najbardziej znany zawodnik na tej pozycji</col>
                
            </row>
            <row>
                <col>Rozgrywający</col>
                <col><link source="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micah_Christenson">Micah Christenson</link></col>
            
            </row>
            <row>
                <col>Libero</col>
                <col><link source="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenia_Grebennikov">Jennia Grebennikov</link></col>
            </row>
            <row>    
                <col>Przyjmujący</col>
                <col><link source="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilfredo_Le%C3%B3n">Wilfredo Leon</link></col>
            </row>
            <row>    
                <col>Atakujący</col>
                <col><link source="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartosz_Kurek">Bartosz Kurek</link></col>
            </row>
            <row>    
                <col>Srodkowy</col>
                <col><link source="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sre%C4%87ko_Lisinac">Srecko Lisinac</link></col>
            </row>
        </tabelka>
    </podstrona>
    
    
    <Animacja_tekstu>
        Prosze o uzupełnienie ankiety :)
    </Animacja_tekstu>
    <formularz>
        <Imie>
        Imie
        </Imie>
        <Nazwisko>
        Nazwisko
        </Nazwisko>
        <plec tryb="zaznacz" Kobieta="kobieta" Mezczyzna="mezczyzna"/>
        Ulubiona marka pilek
        <pilki tryb="zaznacz" >
            Molten
            Mikasa
        </pilki>
        <pozycja tryb="przewin">
            Atakujacy
            Libero
            Srodkowy
            Przyjmujący
            Rozgrywający
        </pozycja>
        <cos tryb="lista">
           <opcja_grupa>
                Nie gram w siatkówkę
                
                    <opcja>nie lubie</opcja>
                    <opcja>nie umiem</opcja>
            
                :(
                    <opcja>nie mam pomyslu</opcja>
                        
                        <opcja>na ta tabelke</opcja>
            </opcja_grupa>
        </cos>
        <text_area>
        Proszę o wpisaniu swoich opini na temat strony :)
        </text_area>
        <wyslij>submit</wyslij>
        <wyczysc>reset</wyczysc>
    </formularz>    
    
</srodek>
```

Comment: When the validation passed then it is a valid XML file. But the validator cannot know if the content itself "makes sense", it only checks the syntax and if the elements/attributes matches the `moje_hobby_xsd` schema.

Comment: You refer to other documents (like `moje_hobby.xsd`) which we can't see. So we can't fully document. Atleast, that is what Visual Studio is flagging when I open your file.

Comment: If by *well done* you are soliciting an subjective opinion, opinion-based questions are off-topic here.  If you are referring to the XML concepts of *well-formed* or *valid*, see the duplicate link for the definitions and differences between those objective terms.

Answer (score 0):

Though the format of XML is fine, the structure of the XML elements should represent the data in a more hierarchical way. That is missing here.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it appears to be a well-formed XML document.